# View current path instead of file name on the window bar

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

This is the area where I wish to instead view the current file path :
[image: Hihglighted example]

Is it possible, and if so how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your User Preferences (**`Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Settings-User`**) and add the following line:

```js
"show_full_path": true,
```

(don't include the comma `,` if it's the last line - it should be valid JSON). This will display the full path to the active file in the window bar.

[image]

You should note that the name of my project (Python3) is also displayed (nothing will be there if you don't have an active project or any folders in the sidebar), and `/Users/UserName` is replaced by `~`.

Comment: The JSON parser ST3 uses for settings is very forgiving of trailing commas, and it is not necessary to remove it for the last preference in the file.

Comment: @Keith has that changed recently? I've been using Sublime for probably 4 years now, and I know I've gotten errors related to this in the past...

Comment: Besides, regardless of whether this parser is forgiving, it's always a good idea to try and format your data according to the spec. You may get into the habit of not checking for trailing commas or whatever, then a real JSON file may fail parsing in another environment.

Comment: not sure I'm afraid - but certainly it has been like this for a while now. Only way to reliably find out exactly when it changed would be to download lots of old portable builds until it complains about the trailing comma ;)